# NSCopying arrays of custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nscopying

I have a Singleton object that manages all my lists. We'll call it ListStore.

ListStore has a mutable array, which stores Lists.

```
@interface ListStore : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *lists; // an array of List objects
end
```

Lists has a mutable array, which stores Things.

```
@interface Wanderlist : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying>
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *things; // an array of Thing objects
@end
```

At any time, a background process might go through ListStore and loop through and process all Lists, while a user might be interacting with a List.

To guard against "object was mutated while being enumerated" type errors, I do this:

```
// all of this is in a background thread
NSArray *newLists = [[ListStore sharedStore] lists] copy];

for (List *list in newLists) {
    // yay, no more crashes, because I'm enumerating over a copied object, so the user
    // can do whatever they want while I'm here

    for(Thing *thing in list.things) {
        // oh crap, my copy and the original object both reference the same list.things,
        // which is why i'm seeing the 'mutation while enumerating" errors still
        ...
    }
}
```

I originally thought that because I made a copy into `newLists` that all of its members would be properly copied. I now understand that not to be the case: I'm still seeing the "object was mutated while enumerated" errors, but this time it's happening on `list.things`.

Can I use NSCopying with my setup so that when I say:

```
[[ListStore sharedStore] copy];
```

It calls `copyWithZone:` on `Lists`, so I can then `copyWithZone:` on `things`?

I tried to set it up like this but `copyWithZone:` wasn't getting called.

I know I could simply say `NSArray *newList = [list.things copy]` but I'd like to get a better understanding of NSCopying at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

Right before submitting this question I clicked on a question in SO's list of related questions, and found my solution.

Figured it doesn't hurt to post my solution.

Instead of this:

```
NSArray *newLists = [[ListStore sharedStore] lists] copy];
```

I had to do:

```
NSArray *newLists = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[ListStore sharedStore] lists] copyItems:true];
```

From [the NSArray docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> ```
> - (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array copyItems:(BOOL)flag
> flag: 
> If YES, each object in array receives a copyWithZone: message to create a copy of the object—objects must conform to the NSCopying protocol. In a managed memory environment, this is instead of the retain message the object would otherwise receive. The object copy is then added to the returned array.
> ```

Once I used initWithArray:copyItems:, it automatically sent copyWithZone to all my List objects, and I was able to then manually perform a copyWithZone on `list.things`.